# Starting rng-tools in SLES guest in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, random

I am trying to start `rng-tools` in a SLES 11 SP3 installation inside of VirtualBox.

```
vagrant@sles11sp3x64:~> uname -a
Linux sles11sp3x64 3.0.93-0.8-default #1 SMP Tue Aug 27 08:44:18 UTC 2013 (70ed288) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

All attempts have been un-successful, with the following output:

```
vagrant@sles11sp3x64:/etc/init.d> sudo /sbin/service rng-tools status
Checking for RNG daemon                                                                                                                                            unused
vagrant@sles11sp3x64:/etc/init.d> sudo /sbin/service rng-tools start
Starting RNG daemon  No Hardware RNG support available                                                                                                             skipped
```

here is the contents of `/etc/default/rng-tools` :

```
vagrant@sles11sp3x64:~> cat /etc/default/rng-tools
HRNGDEVICE=/dev/urandom
```

What am I missing to get VirtualBox to expose my hardware correctly?

Comment: What exactly do you expect should happen? In a VM there usually are no HWRNGs. Clarify please.

Comment: @peterph For a VM, the “hardware RNG” is the RNG of the host.

Comment: @Gilles not really - you would have to *emulate* the HWRNG in the VM (feeding through it the entropy from the host system). `/dev/random` is not a HWRNG, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the virtio-rng kernel module (in the guest). See [this article](http://log.amitshah.net/2013/01/about-random-numbers-and-virtual-machines/) for more details. I'm not sure whether VirtualBox supports it yet - if not, you might want to give [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu-project.org/Features-Done/VirtIORNG) a try.